# How to find the root element in a hierarchical structure

Tags: c#

I have this situation set:

An object with a property "Children", which is a List of the same type. The depth of the structure is unknown. This is, how the object looks like:

```
public class CustomType
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<CustomType> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to search for a specific name and if I've found an element matching this name, I want to know it's root element. For example:

- RootElement

  - AnyElement

    - AnyElement

      - FoundElement

I have the FoundElement already, but I want to know it's top level parent element. I hope my problem is understandable. Main problem is the non existing parent link in the object...

So long
Chris

Comment: How are you doing the search?

Comment: It is impossible if a) you do not have `Parent` property OR b) you do not have `CustomType` reference of the root of the whole tree (but then you would not need to do the search at all). If you have many roots and you store them somewhere - do recursive search for each of them.

Comment: I search the structure recursively

Comment: Do you have a collection of all possible root elements? If not, it's not possible.

Comment: You must have a set of one or more roots, so you need to search each on in turn until you find the item in question or run out of roots to search.

Comment: The current structure doesn't support the search you are after !!!

Comment: @ChrisReingruber so if you search the structure recursively, you already know the root, correct? You have to have a handle to the root to initiate the search.

Comment: @RexM I assume there's more than one root, otherwise the question is trivial

Comment: Can you show us the search code?

Comment: as @BenAaronson mentioned correctly, there are more than one root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the ideal would be to have a `Parent` property on the class. However if it's a requirement not to have that, your approach should be to check all descendents of all candidate root nodes. This can be done recursively like:

```
private bool HasDescendent(CustomType parent, CustomType descendent)
{
    if(parent.Children.Contains(descendent))
        return true;
    return parent.Children.Any(child => HasDescendent(child, descendent);
}

private CustomType FindRoot(IEnumerable<CustomType> candidateRoots, CustomType node)
{
    return candidateRoots.First(root => HasDescendent(root, node));
}
```

Comment: thanks @BenAaronson , this works just fine! I'd like to vote you up but I don't have enough rep ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this would be recursion (I haven't done C# in a while, so here comes some pseudocode):

```
list<items> findPath(root, needle):
    if root == needle:
         return [needle]
    for child in root.children:
         if findPath(child, needle) != Null:
              return [root].concat(findPath(child, needle))
    return Null
```

This should get you the path from the root node to the needle.